# How to merge data source results into existing map of objects

Tags: terraform

I'm somewhat new to Terraform, and I'm stuck on something I'm trying to build.

I'm trying to loop over a map of metadata objects. One of the fields contains a url to a OpenAPI specification. The idea is to generate an Azure APIM API for each schema. I've gotten as far as downloading the specification for each API, but I'm having trouble figuring out how to map the results back into the original map. My reasoning behind this is to have the resturned JSON merged with the original metadata.

Here's the schema of the variable that holds the metadata.

```
variable "open_api_definitions" {
  type = map(map(string))
  default = {
    "apiname" = {
      path : "https://url.to.openapi.spec",
      service_url : "https://endpoint.where.api.will.be.deployed",
      api_name : "apiname",
      api_url_suffix : "path/to/endpoint"
    }
  }
}
```

This is the data source that retrieves the OpenAPI spec

```
data "http" "url_responses" {
  for_each = var.open_api_definitions

  url = each.value.path
}
```

And extracting the responses into a local variable

```
locals {
  http_responses = [for response in data.http.url_responses : {
    id   = response.id
    body = response.response_body
  }]
}
```

Up to this point, everything seems to work. I've used an output block to verify. I'm unsure how to proceed from here. I'd like to see if I can map each response back to the original `open_api_definitions` variable in a new field, or at least create a new map of objects that I can then use to create the APIs. At that point, I know what needs to be done to create the APIs.

EDIT:
I'm hoping to end up with something that looks like this:

```
variable "open_api_definitions" {
  type = map(map(string))
  default = {
    "apiname" = {
      path : "https://url.to.openapi.spec",
      service_url : "https://endpoint.where.api.will.be.deployed",
      api_name : "apiname",
      api_url_suffix : "path/to/endpoint"
      json_body: "{open api spec json}"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: In this situation it would be helpful to display a snippet of the actual results and a snippet of the expected results.

Comment: So the `open_api_definitions` variable exists or not? If I understand this correctly, you want to assign outputs to a default value of the variable?

Comment: It exists. I want to either merge the data source results back into the original variable, or create a new variable with the original fields, plus the response bodies from the data source. I don't really care which.